# Why does a 'body' string appear above the answer box?

Tags: bug, answers, mobile-web

On the mobile version of the site I see a `body` link that actually is not needed:

> [image: mobile answer]

I think it came from the question form, where also there also exists `title` and `tags` fields.

Comment: I think it's a simple overlook by the dev team. Better turn this into a bug report or feature request.